# Why would `rvm install ruby-2.1.0` install preview1?

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-2.1

I just tried to install Ruby 2.1, and instead got 2.1 Preview 1.  This seems crazy to me.  2.1 is out.  Why would RVM assume that when I say `rvm install ruby-2.1.0` that I ***really*** mean `rvm install ruby-2.1.0-preview1`?  Why would it not match the *exact* version I specified, instead of one which begins with that substring?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Silly clarification question (and I would post it as a comment if I had enough reputation), but have you updated RVM lately?

`rvm get stable` (or if you want to live on the edge, `rvm get head`) would, I expect, update the internal list of released ruby versions.

Answer (score 24):

Make sure you are running the latest version. RVM 1.25.8 (or greater) is working as expected.

```
$ rvm get latest
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/1.25.8.tar.gz
```

and

```
$ rvm install 2.1
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
...
ruby-2.1.0 - #downloading ruby-2.1.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
```

and

```
$ rvm use 2.1
Using /Users/weppos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

Comment: I don't recommend using 'ruby install 2.1' [even though the docs say this].  I've seen this fail [like w/ 2.1.5], and you need to say 'rvm install ruby-2.1.5'.  No idea why [it complains about "ambiguous"-ness].